# Using JNI libraries in flink cluster

Tags: java-native-interface, apache-flink, jvm-arguments

I need to use JNI libraries to run the jar on flink cluster.
Can anyone please guide me how to do this?
If it is to be provided using VM arguments then how to pass VM arguments while running the jar using flink cli?
Is there any change need to be madein the flink script?

Answer (score 0):

One way to use JNI library path is to provide a **java.library.path** parameter:

java -Djava.library.path=

You can provide JVM arguments to a task manager (responsible for executing individual Flink tasks) using the **FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS_TM** environment variable:

export FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS_TM="-Djava.library.path="

Comment: This didn't work for me. printenv shows: `FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS_TM=-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/` but the job still fails with `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`